# create a form inside a dll [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a form inside a DLL and to be able to call it from another project. I have done this in Delphi, but I need this in VB.NET (just started using it)

[my test in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077208/move-project-into-dll)

[delphi-central.com](http://www.delphi-central.com/formdll.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can add Reference of System.Windows.Forms assembly and Add a Form. or You can add a Form directly.

```
public void ShowSettings()
{
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Show();
}
```

and you can invoke this method.

Comment: how do I call the form inside a dll from a app?

Comment: You can create instance of Form and can call form.show, I modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think it's much better to create a `User Control` for that. **[See Here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c316f119%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**